# Why do I get the link to the first image of a post instead of the image itself?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, gallery

I'm trying to retrieve and display just the first image of a post on the main blog page...
But the only thing showing up is the link to that image, not the image itself!
Not sure what is wrong!...

Here's the code that is being used to attempt this.

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "";
  }

  return $first_img;
}
```

Thanks for any help... Here's the link to the page with the problem: http://wordpress-dev.designer17.com/blog/ (Bottom post)

Comment: If you have the image url, just put it in an image tag...

Comment: You're extracting only the link, not the entire tag, so if the returned result from that function is inserted directly into the HTML, what do you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the image url, as long as you're just planning on displaying the image directly from that function, you can simply return the img html tag with the url in the src:

```
return '<img src="' . $first_img . '">';
```

Comment: Thanks a Million! I'm still learning so I hadn't even thought of that.
It is now working.

Comment: No problem, there will always be more to learn :) You should also mark this as correct so other people see the question as closed.

Comment: +1 - however, the one drawback of this approach is that you lose other attributes of the image... for the most part this isn't a big deal, however, it means losing the `alt` attribute which makes the markup invalid in some version of html (HTML 4.01, for instance), so depending on the `doctype` of the parent document this may generate invalid markup. You should also make the image tag self-closing: `return '<img src="' . $first_img . '" alt="[this should be populated]" />';`

Comment: @rogMaHall I completely intended on it but couldn't till a specified time from when you answered. :)

Comment: @BenD I'm using HTML5 ... and as of right now I don't need the alt, but I'll keep that it mind!

Comment: @BenD Yes, I totally agree it would be more ideal to include the alt attribute. Because he was only generating the url up to that point, I didn't want to add any extra complexity for him :)

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution of getting the first image and it worked perfectly on my local host but when I copied it to my live host it failed with a subscript error. I therefore modified it to the following which works.

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  if (preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches) == 0) {
    //Define a default image
    $first_img = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/images/default-image.jpg";   
  } else {
    $first_img = $matches [1] [0];
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```